# Detect E-Mail Conversation with Exchange Web Services

Tags: web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is it possible to detect for incoming mails, if they belong a to preceding e-mail conversation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the message has been replied to using a Microsoft email client it should have the [PidTagInReplyToId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200817%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) property set with the id of the message replied to. This will enable you to build up a message chain from each reply to the source email.

Otherwise you'll have to rely on the "Re:" prefix in subjects and common subject names. You could also do something clever regarding who has been sent an email (in case of common subjects) or utilising the previous message body in the new email - though that obviously cannot be relied upon.